# How to copy command line text to host clipboard while using Ubuntu on VmWare?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have host machine running Windows 7 and VmWare running Ubuntu in command line mode. When I am trying to copy content of command line of client machine to host machine - it is not working. There is only `#^C` sign appears in ubuntu command line. Is there a way to copy it?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to copy anything from client machine unless any GUI environment is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste

These are the commands for pasting into the Ubuntu terminal; however, it looks like you have to install VMWare tools on the guest machine as well as the host.

[Source](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1293)